# vba function to grab value from same cell on another specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How do I refer to the same cell position on another sheet, or the same column for that matter inside a VBA function?

details:
Stuck at the start: Not experienced with VBA, which is weird for an R coder.

On a sheet called "Calculations", I am trying to write a function that will grab the value in the same cell, but from a different sheet "RawData" and then manipulate it.

```
Worksheets(“RawData”).?
```

I have tried 100 google searches, but I keep up ending with ActiveCell approaches, which won't work as that refers to where the cursor / selected cell is, not the cell where the function is in.

What is a suitable alternative for

```
ActiveCell.Column
ActiveCell.Row
```

The plan I have is to write 5 to 8 functions, and let excel run the correct one based on the name of the column header or data type instead of writing a 1000 line excel formula.
The first function i'm trying to convert into a VBA function is this one:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Calculations!A:A;MATCH($A14;RawData!$AA$2:$AA$1001;)+1);"")
```

the end  goal would look like a function in the excel sheet that has this design:

```
Public Function Datacleaner() 
If condition x is TRUE: formula1
else if condition y is TRUE apply formula 2
etc 
Return the value to the cell of the formula
End Function
```

Comment: `Worksheets("RawData").Cells(Application.ThisCell.Row, Application.ThisCell.Column).Value`.

Comment: Though ... this won't automatically update if the cell on the `RawData` sheet is changed. Probably better to pass the cell as a parameter.

Comment: Yes that last bit is the objective ben

Comment: So that would mean I need input arguments for the function right?

Comment: That would be better IMO.